# source schema to target schema mapping framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapping

-3

This is for a Spring boot appliction where I have to fetch data from a source Schema which has a set of columns for a given table and each column needs to be mapped to a target column say id_value and needs to be mapped to value_id in the target.

```
{"tableName":"employee",
            "data":
             {"empname":"john"
             ,"empId"  :"100"
             ,"sal"    : "1000" 
             }
}
```

Now in the target schema i need to store the data with a different  column name (Based on some metadata) and store this in a legacy database table

```
{"tableName":"employee",
                "data":
                 {"name_emp":"john"
                 ,"id_emp"  :"100"
                 ,"sal_emp" : "1000" 
                 }
}
```

What would be the best way to do this transformation of COLUMN NAMES in the schema ?Easiest option to manually write getters and setters for each table but that look cumbersome . I have tried to explore Lombok https://projectlombok.org/ which dynamically generates getter and setter on the fly but dont see a way to do a transformation of column names dynamically at run time. Any suggestions welcome

Comment: Have a look at http://mapstruct.org/ and http://modelmapper.org/

Comment: thanks looked t them see option to tranform data type but not the entire column as it

Comment: You don't have to transform anything you just have to map one field to anoter

Comment: thats true . is there a way i can avoid a  metadata config file to store the mapping ? looked in lombok and mapstruct framework dont see  a way to map attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Simon Martinelli . the model mapper approach worked fine. All i need to do is to call the map method

```
ModelMapper        mapper= new ModelMapper();
mapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.LOOSE);
LegacyDTO   legacyDTO=mapper.map(orginalDTO,LegacyDTO.class);
```